# Getting an unauthorized error

Tags: javascript

the overall code is a bit messy as I have been trying different things out and haven't gotten down to organizing them all. I am trying to send a PUT request to the /api/protected with the username and the new email to update the email. This is a protected route which needs the authtoken to access it which I have passed in. I am getting an unauthorized error.

```
function updateProfile(username, email, authToken, callback) {
 const settings = {
    url: '/api/protected',
    data: {      
      username: `${username}`,      
      email: `${email}`,
    headers: {      
      authorization: `Bearer ${authToken}`
    }, 
   },
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'PUT',
    success: callback,
    error: error
  };
  $.ajax(settings); 
}
```

This is the ajax request and now in the server side code:

```
app.put('/api/protected', jwtAuth, (req, res) => {
 const updatedItem = User.update({username: req.body.username}, {$set:{email: req.body.email}})  
 return res.status(201).json({updatedItem});  
});
```

Comment: I am open to suggestions on how to improve regarding the downvote.

Comment: You could start by removing code not relevant to the question.

Comment: @ScottHunter, I removed the code not relevant to the question.

Comment: You have `headers` *within* the `data` setting. I believe it has to be outside of it to add an actual header.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan, that was the reason it was throwing the error. Thank you. Please post your comment as the answer. Although its actually now throwing a 500 error.

Comment: Assuming the username and email are already strings, you don't need to enclose them in [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), you could just use the bare variables: `data: {username: username, email: email},`. If you are only targeting [recent browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Browser_compatibility), you could even use the ES2015 style short-hand property names `data: {username, email}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we look at [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings), we see that the `headers` property should be on the settings sent to `$.ajax`, not within the `data` property. To remedy, simply move it out of the `data` property. For example:

```js
function updateProfile(username, email, authToken, callback) {
  const settings = {
    url: '/api/protected',
    data: {
      username: `${username}`,
      email: `${email}`,
    },
    headers: {
      authorization: `Bearer ${authToken}`
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'PUT',
    success: callback,
    error: error
  };
  $.ajax(settings);
}
```

Note that I've also cleaned up the indentation a bit to make it easier to see the correct placement.